# Save data of html form into SharePoint list using JS , with impersonation

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, content-editor-web-part, public-website

I have a SharePoint public site and make it as online, I created a list called "questionnaire result".
I designed an HTML page for questionnaire by people, then I added the `ContentEditor` WebPart with script of save form into "questionnaire result" list, and everyone can open this page and submit form to save it into this list.

My question is:

How can people submit form and don't have edit permission in this list?
Can I make `Impersonating` in my script to be save item by SharepointApp account?

Answer (score 0):

If you have made this list as public than you can apply the unique permission on this list.

Go to list setting-> Permission for this list->Click on Stop Inheriting permission from Ribbon ->Click on Grant Permission and give Edit permission to everyone.

Using this , All users can edit this single list from the site[image]

Comment: Or if you want user to add the record only, not to delete or update. in that case you can create the custom permission role with add item permission only and than assign that custom role to everyone so all user can submit the request only.they can not edit or delete the request.

Comment: i tried that , the list is not appear for users maybe Everyone mean all the sharepoint users and external users that i share this site to him , and i want to make this list also for any user

Comment: in that case i think you need to Enable anonymous access on a list or library

you can find more detail at https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Enable-anonymous-access-3647CDD5-1AB8-48CF-B4EE-D1B652BBABDD

Comment: i tried it , but i don't know why anonymous users option is disable , see this image 
![Valid XHTML](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-cMHpR0h6jWw/Wjvd7XCrvKI/AAAAAAAADQc/1LM-91bPxAk_n7TRp6HpBeOuRjY46xwCACLcBGAs/s1600/12.png) , maybe because the feature of public site will remove soon !!

Comment: i can't edit the permission of anonymous users , do you have any idea about why?

Comment: Are you using O365 or OnPremise?

Comment: i am using O365

Comment: In that case public sharing is disabled in Office 365. you can not share the site to anonymous users. it only allowed to share site with Microsoft account.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3027254/sharepoint-online-public-websites-to-be-discontinued

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is unsafe. If users don't have permission to add a new item, you should not save their data in a list.

I suggest you create a custom permission level which only contains "New list item" for this list, then grant this custom permission level to users.

If you really want to achieve it by impersonation identity, you can use CSOM:
[What is the command to elevate privileges in the Sharepoint Online (Office 365)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178904/what-is-the-command-to-elevate-privileges-in-the-sharepoint-online-office-365)

Comment: i created java script code directly to Content Editor web part on my page ( to insert html form into sharepoint list ) , but i cant update my script to be save item by system account (impersonation ) , can you help me to achieve  it , with thanks